# Strange pixelation when previewing a material

Tags: materials, color, versions

I am trying to add a basic color to an object. But whatever Suface I choose, I end up having these strange colorizations/pixelations.

[image]

By the way, if I turn to e.g. Viewport shading, my whole viewport is showing the same symptoms...

Maybe my hardware is too old? I only noticed this after installing Blender latest version.

I basically get something like this in my Viewport:

[image]

Comment: Might have been the Render Engine ...

Comment: This look like an issue with your graphics driver or GPU. Install the latest graphics driver for your GPU and check whether your hardware is supported by 2.80. https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/